# Python program having difficulty in passing test: program execution stalls when input is "unexpected"

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm attempting to write a program that counts the amount of numbers in a user input, sums and averages these numbers, and prints the amount of negative and positive numbers in the numbers. Here's what I have written so far:

```
number = int(input("Please type in integer numbers. Type in 0 to finish."))
amount_of_numbers = 0
sum_of_numbers = 0
mean_of_numbers = 0
positive = 0
negative = 0
while number != 0:
    if number != 0:
        amount_of_numbers += 1
        sum_of_numbers += number
        mean_of_numbers += number
        if number > 0:
            positive += 1
        else:
            negative += 1
        number = int(input("Please type in integer numbers. Type in 0 to finish."))
    else:
        quit()

if amount_of_numbers != 0:
    mean_of_numbers = mean_of_numbers / amount_of_numbers
    amount_of_numbers = str(amount_of_numbers)
    print("Numbers typed in " + amount_of_numbers)
    sum_of_numbers = str(sum_of_numbers)
    print("The sum of the numbers is " + sum_of_numbers)
    mean_of_numbers = str(mean_of_numbers)
    print("The mean of the numbers is " + mean_of_numbers)
    positive = str(positive)
    print("Positive numbers " + positive)
    negative = str(negative)
    print("Negative numbers " + negative)
else:
    pass
```

I tried to use several test cases that I believed may cause error, such as inputting a 0 initially, etc. However, I continually receive a particular error (it is my homework so I have to use an online compiler.) I've attached the error case below.

```
FAIL: WorkingWithNumbersTest: test_1_start

'Please type in integer numbers. Type in 0 to finish.' != 'Numbers typed in 3'
- Please type in integer numbers. Type in 0 to finish.
+ Numbers typed in 3
 : At the start of execution of the program, your program should print out:
Please type in integer numbers. Type in 0 to finish.
your program printed out:
Numbers typed in 3
The sum of the numbers is 6
The mean of the numbers is 2.0
Positive numbers 3
Negative numbers 0
```

I'm not sure what is wrong with my program, since everything I try works. Any tips/help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `At the start of execution of the program, your program should print out:
Please type in integer numbers. Type in 0 to finish.` so I guess that you did not print this out hence this error. Try submitting a code with only that print statement and see if the error changes

Comment: @Caridorc I already tried submitting just 0 and the program terminates the way it should.

Comment: A program that only prints 0?

Comment: @Caridorc That output is in the prompt argument to all the `input()` calls.

Comment: It appears as if you submit different code than what you are editing and running locally.

Comment: Ok, so now you have one version of the code that has one error message and another version with another error message. Add code line by line to the working one until the error changes to identify the cause

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the testing framework only expects the prompt to appear once - i.e., the inputs are not explicitly prompted.

Also, it's arguably better to simplify the input such that all you do is build a list of the values entered then analyse them retrospectively.

Something like this:

```
numbers = []

print('Please type in integer numbers. Type in 0 to finish.')

while n := int(input()):
    numbers.append(n)

if numbers:
    print(f'Numbers typed in {len(numbers)}')
    print(f'The sum of the numbers is {sum(numbers)}')
    print(f'The mean of the numbers is {sum(numbers)/len(numbers)}')
    print(f'Positive numbers {sum(x > 0 for x in numbers)}')
    print(f'Negative numbers {sum(x < 0 for x in numbers)}')
```